# How to bind values to checkboxfor in mvc 4 entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

This is my Model.

```
public partial class Tm_Screen
    {
        public int Screen_Id { get; set; }
        public string Screen_name { get; set; }
        public string Screen_Desc { get; set; }
        public string IsActive { get; set; }
   }
```

I want to bind ScreenName to checkbox for control. In db i have data. I want to bind.
I changed something like this

This is controller code.

```
 var list = new List<tm_scrn_screen>
                   {
                       new tm_scrn_screen{scrn_name="csscs",scrn_isactive=true}
                   };

                return View( list);
```

This is view code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
   {
        <table>  
      <tr>  
         <td>  

            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].scrn_name)  
         </td>  
         <td>  
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].scrn_isactive)  
         </td>  
      </tr>  
   </table>  

   }
```

this is not working.
Some red mark is coming near m => m[i].scrn_name

Comment: Checkbox usually has two primary states checked or unchecked. I wonder what of the checkbox you want to bind with the Screen_name

Comment: I am new to mvc. But i want checkboxlist that contains some values. Finally checked values i want to save in db

Comment: Also i want to bind data only whose Isactive is true

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Change the type to Boolean and for Screen_Name use the `DisplayNameFor` helper for automatically obtaining its name from the model.

Comment: Okay i changed isactive to boolean. Can you tell me in bit detail? Do i need to put any loops here?

Comment: I tried something like this but it wont give desired result.@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.scrn_name)

Comment: I tried something like this also but not working  @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.scrn_id)
@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.scrn_name)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.scrn_isactive)
@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.scrn_name)

Comment: There is no point putting some vague code in comments and claiming it does not work. Edit your question to show your controller and view code and indicate what is not working.

Comment: I have edited the code. I am getting error near m => m[i].scrn_name....

Comment: @NIRANJANG, You need to explain what the error is (go to the help files and learn how to ask a question if you want to get help on this site). And you have a model with `public string IsActive { get; set; }` but your code is referring to a property named `scrn_isactive` so you have not even shown the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CheckBox is primary intended to represent a single Boolean field. If you want it to show a list of values and let user check several, you need custom code. Usually the way would be multi select no checkbox list. But if you need it could find several implementations as [this](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/how-to-use-checkboxlistfor-with-aspnet.html?m=1), [this](http://mvccbl.com) or [this](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/how-to-use-checkboxlistfor-with-aspnet.html?m=1). Simply google it you'll find lot of examples

Comment: Yes i got it but  i didnt get any example which bind data from database.

Comment: i want to bind data to checkboxlist from database. Links you provided are just hard coded

Comment: Can you suggest me what i should write in action method and view?

Comment: i did not get any articles related to my requirement

Comment: But you can't just populate the list of options from query instead of typing it hardcoded? As in any other regular database operation?

Comment: oh okay i did not knew it. So if i have to hardcode then what is the use of model?

Comment: Sorry it's difficult for me to understand what do you need. I don't know what do you mean with "hardcoded" there aren't  hard coding in any of the suggested links. You have 2 different problems (I suppose): 1) to represent a list of options as checkboxes to let user choose some (my links), and 2) to populate that list from db (and to update it). Those are 2 totally different things. You could first make one work (maybe with hc data) anda once you get it replace the hc data with a simple query.

Comment: i need small checkboxlist and i need to bind data from database.

Comment: i edited my question. i am trying to display one checkboxlist. Really its fraustrating

Comment: in above code i hardcoded data actually i want that data should come from db

Comment: You razor syntax is wrong, you would suggest foreach(var item in Model) and then m=>item.propname. Or just replace m[] by Model[]

Comment: i changed as you said now all view decorated with red color errors

Comment: Maybe you need some mvc/razor tutorials before going forward. This is beyond checkboxes. Mvc crud scaffolding over entities build simple views for crud showing all this except checkbox list, I would recommend first master that and then return to checkboxlist

Comment: https://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/checkboxlist-in-asp-net-mvc4/comment-page-1/#comment-1088 I FOLLOWED THIS. hERE ALSO  i m getting error near model.count in view

Comment: i am not able to iterate